# Creating 10 circles in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash

Iam trying to create a simple method in AS3 that adds 10 circles, each 30px in diameter in a column down the left-hand-side of the stage, so the first appears in the top-left corner and the last in the bottom-right. I would appreciate any help here. Thanks.

My current code follows: - It currently just returns 10 circles with no positioning.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Circles extends MovieClip
    {
        private var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 10);

        public function Circles()
        {

            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, createCircles);
            timer.start();
        }
        private function createCircles(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            var bcircle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            var xpos:int = 0;
            var ypos:int = 0;

                bcircle.graphics.beginFill(0x0033CC);
                bcircle.graphics.drawCircle(xpos,ypos,15);
                bcircle.graphics.endFill();
                bcircle.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                bcircle.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                addChild(bcircle);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You mean that the circles have to first continue down along the left edge of the stage, and then continue to the right from there on until they reach bottom right corner of the stage? Like one half of a picture frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
bcircle.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
bcircle.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
```

These are the lines you want to be paying attention to as these lines control where each circle is placed when added to the stage.

Circle diameter = 30px, stage height (for example) = 400px.
30 goes into 400 13.33 times (400/30) so each circle needs to be spaced 13.3px further down than the last.

You can store a variable that counts how many circles are already on the stage and use it to multiply 13.3 to find the appropriate `y` value:

```
var i:int = 0;
private function createCircles(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var bcircle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var xpos:int = 0;
    var ypos:int = 0;

    bcircle.graphics.beginFill(0x0033CC);
    bcircle.graphics.drawCircle(xpos,ypos,15);
    bcircle.graphics.endFill();
    bcircle.x = 0;
    bcircle.y = (30 + 13.3) * i; // First circle placed at 0, Second placed at 43.3...
    i++; // Increment i each time function is called
    addChild(bcircle);
}
```

You can apply a similar method to then increment the `x` position of each circle once i reaches 10 (10 circles have been placed), use a trigger to detect this: `if(i == 10)`

Comment: Thanks Sim I really appreciate this help. Is there a way to output circle duplicate circles to the display without using the 'Math.random() * stage.stageWidth' I previously used. Currently I can only output one.

Comment: Yes if you hard code a value (x = 3) it will ALWAYS be 3, but in the above example the use of `i` makes it different every time the function is ran.  I'm not quite sure what you mean about duplicate circles though, did you try the code I posted above?

Comment: Yes I tried this code but only one circle is returned to the display, I needed 10 circles, so 10 'bcircle' on the display at the same time.

Comment: Ah well keep the code that initialises and starts the timer you setup, that will call the `createCircles` function 10 times and create 10 circles.

Comment: I uploaded the full code with modifications to draw 10 circles down the left side here: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2a93

Answer (score 0):

This might help ...

```
package {
  import flash.display.Graphics;
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.utils.Timer;

  public class Circles extends Sprite {

    private const _circles:Array = []; // reusable container
    private var _timer:Timer;

    public function Circles() {
      _timer = new Timer(1000, 10);
      _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer_timerHandler);
      _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timer_timerCompleteHandler);

      _timer.start();
    }

    private function createCircle():Sprite {
      const sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

      drawCircleInGraphics(sprite.graphics);

      addChild(sprite);

      return sprite;
    }

    private function drawCircleInGraphics(graphics:Graphics, color:uint = 0x0033CC, radius:uint = 15):void {
      graphics.beginFill(color);
      graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
      graphics.endFill();
    }

    private function createNewCircleAndPositionIt():void {
      _circles[_circles.length] = createCircle();

      if (_circles.length > 1) {
        const last:Sprite = _circles[_circles.length - 1],
            predecessor:Sprite = _circles[_circles.length - 2];

        last.x = predecessor.x + 30;
        last.y = predecessor.y + 30;
      }
    }

    private function timer_timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
      createNewCircleAndPositionIt();
    }

    private function timer_timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
      _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer_timerHandler);
      _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timer_timerCompleteHandler);
      _timer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Florian Salihovic, this is similar to what I was trying to achieve. I need tp use this and adapt it to position the circles like an L shape, top left of stage to bottom right of stage. Thanks this is a great start.